# additional plugins required firefox on windows for javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, firefox, d3.js

I have a web page, written entirely in javascript, html, and css, that I'm trying to launch. However, when a windows user on firefox tries to access the page, only about 2/3 of it displays and the user gets the error "Additional plugins are required to display all media on this page". I'm especially confused because the page includes a user input form and a d3 generated graph, and the left half of the graph displays but not the right half (and the entire user input form displays properly). If the user doesn't have Quicktime installed, he is prompted to install it. If he does have it installed, no prompt shows up but the page still doesn't properly display.

What it looks like on Chrome 
[image: What it looks like on chrome]

What it looks like on Firefox
[image: what it looks like on firefox]

Any advice on how to get this to display properly on firefox?

Comment: Try taking a look at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/954280 or https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/936504 ?

Comment: Opened http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/science-of-cooking/home-screen.html in Firefox 23 OSX, and it does seem to work/does not exhibit the behavior you're describing. Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.